# Grab content around each occurrence with regex

Tags: python, json, regex

**Use Case**

I want to use regex to grab a very small part of json data with unknown location. Although Python has a json library, parsing all json data is slow.
The json data has regular format.

**Goal**

For each occurrence of `1001`, I want to grab content in the innermost braces that enclose the occurrence

**Code**

```
import re
x = r'{123:{"a":100, "asdf":"example.com","at":1001},'\
    '47289:{"a":20, "asdf":"test.org","at":20},}'
regex = r'{(.*?)1001(.*?)}'
print(re.match(regex, x).group(1))
```

**Desired Result**

```
{"a":100, "asdf":"example.com","at":1001}
```

**Actual Result**

```
123:{"a":100, "asdf":"example.com","at":
```

**Questions**

How to do this? How to do this fast?

Comment: @Pedro Lobito: I was thinking about compile once and then run on many json. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808913/using-json-or-regex-when-processing-tweets gave me the idea that regex is faster in some cases.

Comment: I doubt about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808913/using-json-or-regex-when-processing-tweets even if it's the accepted answer. You may want to profile both options to see which one's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.*?`, it will match any characters, including `{`. Use `[^{]*?` instead.

You also need to use `re.search()`, not `re.match()`, since `match()` only matches at the beginning of the string. See [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match).

And to get the entire match, use `.group(0)`. `.group(1)` just returns the part that matches `[^}]*?`.

```
import re
x = r'{123:{"a":100, "asdf":"example.com","at":1001},'\
    '47289:{"a":20, "asdf":"test.org","at":20},}'
regex = r'{([^{]*?)1001(.*?)}'
print(re.search(regex, x).group(0))
```

Making it non-greedy doesn't solve the problem, because matching goes left-to-right. So `{` will match the first `{`, then `.*` will match everything until `1001`, which includes the inner `{`.

It works as expected for the second group because the non-greedy quantifier stops before the first `}`, since it's working left-to-right.

Comment: that means the regexp isn't matching anything. You should check with it was succesful before trying to use the result.

Comment: @duh1234 Use `re.search()`.

Comment: I use regex101.com.

Comment: Use `group(0)` to get the whole match, not `group(1)`.

Comment: duh. Thanks a lot.